Typescript says the property does not exist
I’m fairly new to generic/typescrypt.
Context: Im trying to pass data from a page (page.tsx) to a generic component (header.tsx). The data is fetched from a react-query function.
Issue: In the header.tsx, the Checkbox component, Typescrypt is saying:

Property every does not exist on type T


Parameter 'record' implicitly has an 'any' type

And I am quite confused as to why that is the case when the data I’m passing is guaranteed to be an array and exists.
What I thought: TypeScript also notifies that record has an any type, but my thought process was that since the component doesn’t recognize the type of the data prop, if I was able to somehow get the type for the data prop in headers.tsx, TypeScript can then infer it.
I have attached a link to the playground.
types.ts
export type ProductRow = {
    id: string;
    name?: string;
    sku?: string;
};

page.tsx
export const page = () => {
  //data fetched from react-query useQuery
  const data = [
    {
      brand: {
        id: 'clywipo320000cayabq4iub7e', 
        name: 'Nero', 
        minMargin: 30, 
        maxMargin: 40, 
      },
      id: '1',
      name: "100mm Round Tile Insert Floor Waste 50mm Outlet Brushed Gold",
      priceRecords: [
          {
              price: 120, 
              date: 'Fri Aug 23 2024 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)'
          }
      ],
      sku: 'NRFW003GD'
    },
    {
      brand: {
        id: 'clywipo320000cayabq4iub7e', 
        name: 'Nero', 
        minMargin: 30, 
        maxMargin: 40, 
      },
      id: '2',
      name: "100mm Round Tile Insert Floor Waste 50mm Outlet Brushed Bronze",
      priceRecords: [
          {
              price: 112, 
              date: 'Fri Aug 23 2024 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)'
          }
      ],
      sku: 'NRFW003BZ'
    }
  ]

  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState<ProductRow[]>([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header data={data} selectedRows={selectedRows} />
      { data.map(record => 
        <input 
            type={`checkbox`} 
            checked={selectedRows.map(row => row.id).includes(record.id)} 
            onClick={() => setSelectedRows(prevValue => [...prevValue, { id: record.id, name: record.name, sku: record.sku }])} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

header.tsx
type HeaderProps<T> = {
  data: T,
  selectedRows: ProductRow[]
};

export const Header = <T,>({ data, selectedRows }: HeaderProps<T>) => {
  return (
    <div className={``}>
      <div className={`flex gap-3 items-start`}>
        <input 
          type={`checkbox`}
          checked={data.every(record => selectedRows.map(row => row.id).includes(record.id))}
        />
        <p>SKU</p>
      </div>
      <p className={`col-span-3`}>Product Name</p>
      <p>Brand</p>
      <p className={`text-center`}>RRP</p>
      <p className={`text-center`}>Max Discount (%)</p>
      <p className={`text-center`}>Buildmat Price</p>
      <p className={`text-center`}>TheBlueSpace Price</p>
    </div>
  )
};


Which line is giving you that error?

is it because you have data.priceRecords = { which then has a subkey priceRecords?  i.e. data.priceRecords.priceRecords = [] but data.priceRecords = {}

@dave Hi, I made a typo on the sample data, it doesnt have a subkey.

@Dai In header.tsx, checked={priceRecords.every(record => selectedRows.map(row => row.id).includes(record.id))} is where the error message is shown

I guess nothing is constraining your T generic to be an array, so it may not necessarily have an every method

Please [edit] so your code is a [mre] we can just copy and paste into our IDEs to see what you're seeing. That means you should remove anything not directly relevant to your problem, especially if it causes unrelated errors for others (e.g., importing private things like ProductRow and Checkbox}).

@jcalz Thanks for the advice, I added some more to clarify the usage of the ProductRow since I think it can be helpful

It really seems like it's not directly relevant. I see a bunch of errors and you're only asking about one of them, right? Please [edit] to make a [mre] where the only problems present are the ones you're asking about, so that any suggestion can be tested.

It would be best if you had just copied and pasted the code as is. data.priceRecords[0].date has an illegal value and I suspect you intended it to be a String. Secondly, you must use comma separators to separate every field from others in a JavaScript and or TypeScript object literal. Thirdly, data is not declared before assignment. The example above is filled with errors. Please make it a [mre].

The playground link is corrupted, and if you have a way of showing it in the playground, please [edit] to give us just that code as plaintext instead of showing multi-file code. The goal of a [mre] is to quickly let people copy and paste into their own IDEs to see what you're seeing (a playground link is a nice supplement but it does not suffice).

@jcalz Thanks for the advice, i have added a useable playground link and edit the code to be minimal reproducible piece of code

So, is T supposed to be the type of data or the type of the elements of data? Is T supposed to have an id property? Something like this approach might be what you're looking for, but you need to tell us what your intent with T is, here.

@jcalz i tried that <T extends { id: string }> and it worked but I kinda want to see if the types can be infer from the data im passing from props with having to declare it

Hmm, I'm not understanding you, sorry. The line data.every(record => selectedRows.map(row => row.id).includes(record.id)) only makes sense if data has an every method, which presumably means it's an array, and if each element of that array has a record property. That means you need to decide what T means. If T really is the type of data then presumably you want to constrain it to {id: string}[] in Header as shown here. But you need to tell us your intent there. I'm not sure how you can expect it to be inferred from anything.

@jcalz for example, if I want to add another fields like sku or name then I also have to include it in like so <T extends { id: string, sku: string, name: string }> then it kinda defeat the purpose of having typescrypt infer it from the data im passing in

Inside Header, how does it know what data you're passing in? Doesn't that depend on how Header is called? TypeScript doesn't infer function parameters from the set of all call sites. Yes, if you want the implementation body of Header to know about sku or name then you need to mention those properties in the call signature, just like if you want function foo(x: unknown) {x.toUpperCase()} to work, you'd need to write x: string instead of x.unknown. It's not something TypeScript can infer.

(see prev comment) Anyway I need to go to sleep now. If you want to see an answer with constraints on T I can write it, otherwise if you're looking for some kind of inference I don't understand, maybe someone else will come along.

This particular concept was discussed in the handbook under Generic Constraints. [typescriptlang.org]
Basically, if want to write a generic function that works on a set of types where you have some knowledge about what capabilities that set of types will have, it is completely normal. The only issue with this is that the compiler cannot prove that every type has a given property, so it must warn you that you can’t make this assumption which seems reasonable because in your case, what if typeof data.priceRecords doesn’t return a type that has a property every()?
The concept of generic constraints is basically the idea that we should constrain our generic procedure to work with any type T but for any property that must be used on T, that property must be assured to exist.

interface EveryWise {
  every(callbackfn: (value, index: number, array) => boolean, thisArg?: any): boolean;
}

export const Header = <T extends EveryWise>({ data, selectedRows }: HeaderProps<T>) => { /* •••Rest of code••• */ }
Example of Generic Constraint. [1]

[1] The interface EveryWise should be constrained even more with a type U representing the type of value but since the type of value is left out, this is the strictest we can go. The reason for this mention is that record is of type any hence record.id is used without type safety.
